# Using DATEPART to CASE in SQLServer to check the month and days only

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT CAST(
             CASE 
                  WHEN n_asset_acquisitionDate = GETDATE() 
                     THEN .../*UPDATE SOMETHING*/
             END AS float) as Depreciation, * 
FROM normal_asset
```

hi i'm new to using `CAST` and really needed this kind of approach, what will happen is that I just want the `WHEN n_asset_acquisitionDate` to just check the `GETDATE()` only per month and day so that every month it will do the update. Any comment, methods, advice, approach is fine,  
P.S.:
I've read in this [thread][1] that using `CASE` is bad? I really don't understand.

[1]: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx 
EDIT:
What happens is that I am incrementing a `numeric` column. So that every month(day of the inserted month) it will increment. So for example

```
n_asset_acquisitionDate   n_asset_ul
2017-2-13                 1
2017-2-13                 4
2017-2-15                 4
```

So in March 13 when I run the query it will go like this

```
n_asset_acquisitionDate   n_asset_ul
2017-2-13                 2
2017-2-13                 5
2017-2-15                 4
```

Comment: You cant update inside a `SELECT`  with or without `CASE`, so you show us exactly what you want update and we help you to write the `UPDATE` statement.     Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Oh, I've never tried updating before because I can't yet think of the solution in the `WHEN`. Will edit now

Comment: BTW, the thread is for some scenarios, `CASE` are very usefull to simplify querys

Comment: Hello I've updated my question

Comment: sorry but the logic isnt clear,.

Answer (score 0):

You can just update with a where clause::

```
UPDATE normal_asset
SET n_asset_ul = n_asset_ul + 1
WHERE n_asset_acquisitionDate = convert(date, GETDATE())
```

Comment: But I only need the day and month.